# Changing Date Format to month dd, yyyy from default in ssrs 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a date parameter in ssrs 2008 formatted by default, like `YYYY-DD-MM` (like 2015-03-31). What I want is to reflect this as `Month dd, yyyy`

I tried adding an expression like: `=Format(Parameters!startDate.Value, "MMMM d, yyyy")` -> however, It is writing "MMMM d, yyyy" as string to the textbox instead a date!

I tried to go to Number section of the expression, selected "Date" there and selected the format I wanted, didnt work. I did the same process by rightclicking the cell after then coming to  the textbox properties, but again did not work.

I dont know what else to try. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your parameter Date data type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presumme your parameter is Text data type or somehow you cast the date value to a string.

You can either cast the value of your parameter to a date, something like this:

```
=FORMAT(CDATE(Parameters!startDate.Value),"MMMM d,yyyy")
```

Or you can go to `Parameter Properties`, in `General`, select `Date` as `Data Type` property.

Then just format using your expression:

```
=Format(Parameters!startDate.Value, "MMMM d, yyyy")
```

If you set the parameter as `Date` data type, a datepicker appears in the parameter pane at runtime for populating the parameter.

Both approaches produce:

```
march 31, 2015
```

Let me know if this helps.